# How to perform combinatoric task in C#

Tags: c#, math, calculator, combinatorics

i have a problem with an combinatoric task. I want to have a code which can handle this math calculation 48/5 = 1712304 (5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120 48*47*46*45*44 = 205476480    205476480/120 = 1712304)

Here some more details.
I have a string array with 48 strings. The strings have a length between 2 and 3 chars.

```
string array[] = new string[]{"A1","1D","410" /*[....]*/}
```

i want to combine 5 strings together, and i want to do this with the whole array, my biggest problem is that a combined string is just allowed to include each of the 48 strings just once. And each combined string have to be unique.

In the end i need a List with 1712304 string entries, which have to be between 10 and 15 degits long. For example one string could look like this "A11A4103E1T".

Back to the math, i know that there are 1712304 combined options so any other result must be wrong. That's where my problem appears.

I created the following code without succesful result

```
        string[] siDigit = new string[iNumDigits];
        List<string> liste = new List<string>();
        const int iDigitBase = 48;
        const int iNumDigits = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1712303; ++i)
        {
            int i2 = i;
            for (int i3 = 0; i3 < iNumDigits; ++i3)
            {
                siDigit[i3] = array[i2 % iDigitBase];
                i2 /= iDigitBase;
            }
            bool duplicate_free = siDigit.Distinct().Count() == siDigit.Length;
            if (duplicate_free == true)
            {
                liste.Add(siDigit[0] + siDigit[1] + siDigit[2] + siDigit[3] + siDigit[4]);
                Console.Write(siDigit[0] + siDigit[1] + siDigit[2] + siDigit[3] + siDigit[4]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

What i get is way to less entries in my list, i just get 1317051 entries and dont know why. I cant find any solution for my problem, may someone out there can help me out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S In germany they dont teach better english :)

Comment: Are there any outer loops which you haven't included in the snippet?  If not, I don't see how there could possibly be more than 1712304 items in the list.

Comment: If this is not a homework requiring you to write the meat of the algorithm yourself, use a 3rd party library like [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Combinatorics/). Note that you probably can't store the results all at once in memory. The library I linked gives you an IEnumerable that you enumerate one by one.

Comment: Well i edit my post, i am so confused that i didnt recognize i wrote a comment to my old code, sorry for that mistake. As i dont go to school anymore it is no homework ;)

Comment: unless im missing something is it not just `string.Join(array.Distinct())`?

Comment: i guess you are missing something. as i dont want to delete duplicates from an existing array or things like that. the problem is that i dont can create my entries correctly

Comment: @ cynic the libary works just perfect for me and Guozis post too. Now i have to working solutions for my problem thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your algorithm is wrong.

Consider i equals 0, i2 equals 0, so siDigit[i3](i3 = 0, 1, 2, 3 ,4) are array[0], duplicate_free is false. You lose one. So, you can not get all entries.

Here is a recursive algorithm:

```
private static void GetCombination(ref List<string[]> list, string[] t, int n, int m, int[] b, int M)
{
    for (int i = n; i >= m; i--)
    {
        b[m - 1] = i - 1;
        if (m > 1)
        {
            GetCombination(ref list, t, i - 1, m - 1, b, M);
        }
        else
        {
            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new List<string[]>();
            }
            string[] temp = new string[M];
            for (int j = 0; j < b.Length; j++)
            {
                temp[j] = t[b[j]];
            }
            list.Add(temp);
        }
    }
}

public static List<string[]> GetCombination(string[] t, int n)
{
    if (t.Length < n)
    {
        return null;
    }
    int[] temp = new int[n];
    List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
    GetCombination(ref list, t, t.Length, n, temp, n);
    return list;
}
```